# Specifying 2D nav goal in rviz for more than one robot?

Tags: ros, rviz, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a user interface were I use the "2D Nav Goal" in rviz to specify goal positions for a robot. Now I need to start two rviz and specify the foal for different robots. Hoq can I do that? The goal is published on "/move_base_simple/goal" and I cannot find any way to specify a namespace for that topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60459/specifying-2d-nav-goal-in-rviz-for-more-than-one-robot?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Enable the 'tool properties' panel, there you can change the topic name. Or, start rviz and [remap](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments) the topic name.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-04-11**:
I tried "rqt -s rqt_rviz/RViz --args move_base_simple:=uav/0" but that did not work. Do you have a command line that works?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-04-11**:
Changing in the tools property panel worked. Thanks.